# Retrieve text from website using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, text-mining

I am trying to retrieve the customer reviews for a particular product from "thehomedepot" website. I have used rvest package to do so. I am able to retrieve the reviews but it comes out to be only the first 10-15 reviews not more than that. I have been trying since such a long time. I couldn't solve this issue.

The reviews are divided into multiple pages. I tried to retrieve the text page by page but when I try to inspect the element of the page, all the reviews from every page is in the same continuous code. There is no difference in each page i.e. it doesn't come by page number also. And the element looks like this with "div" and "span" tags:
[pic of the html code of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9y50v.png)

## my code looks like this:

```
url <- "http://www.homedepot.com/p/Whirlpool-33-in-W-21-2-cu-ft-Side-by-   Side-Refrigerator-in-Monochromatic-Stainless-Steel WRS322FDAM/204099753#customer_reviews" 
home_url <-  read_html(url) %>%
html_nodes("#customer_reviews, .section") 
review <- home_url %>%
html_nodes('#BVRRSourceID, .span') %>%
html_text()
review.text1 <- gsub("[^A-Za-z\\-]|\\.+", " ", review)
review.text2 <- gsub("\n|[ \t]+", " ", review.text1)  
review.text3 <- gsub("Rated out of by", " ", review.text2,ignore.case=T)
review.final <- gsub("August - - bvseo-cps-pl-PRR document getElementById  BVRRContentValidationID style display none - - T - bvseo lps prod bvrr vn prr cp- bvpage co hasreviews tv tr loc en US sid prod sort default" , "",review.text3,ignore.case=T)
print(review.final)
```

Please can someone help me out?

## the sample output looks like this

**reviewers   AlexBigPants Worst delivery service ever- Great fridge for the price Delivery team was awful and made the process for purchase a nightmare Local store was great about picking up the slack My buddy Mike was a huge help in installing these products If you want a quality product at a .....**

Comment: I am sorry, is something wrong with it?? Am I not supposed to do it. But there are a lot of people who scrape the websites I have seen so many question on that. I am really not aware of that. @hrbrmstr

Comment: As in, if you don't mind can you please elaborate. So do you know of any website on which I can do this project?

Comment: @hrbrmstr ..hi you there!